# Apache Spark: stepwise execution

Tags: apache-spark

Due to a performance measurement I want to execute my scala programm written for spark stepwise, i.e.

```
execute first operator; materialize result;
execute second operator; materialize result;
...
```

and so on. The original code:

```
var filename = new String("<filename>")
var text_file = sc.textFile(filename)
var counts = text_file.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
counts.saveAsTextFile("file://result")
```

So I want the execution of `var counts = text_file.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)` to be stepwise.

Is calling `counts.foreachPartition(x => {})` after every operator the right way to do it?

Or is writing to /dev/null with `saveAsTextFile()` a better alternative? And does spark actually have something like a NullSink for that purpose? I wasn't able to write to /dev/null with `saveAsTextFile()` because /dev/null already exists. Is there a way to overwrite the spark result folder?

And does the temporary result after each operation should be cached with `cache()`?

What is the best way to separate the execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark supports two types of operations: actions and transformations. Transformations, as the name implies, turn datasets into new ones through the combination of the transformation operator and (in some cases, optionally) a function provided to the transformation. Actions, on the other hand, run through a dataset with some computation to provide a value to the driver.

There are two things that Spark does that makes your desired task a little difficult: it bundles non-shuffling transformations into execution blocks called stages and stages in the scheduling graph must be triggered through actions.

For your case, provided your input isn't massive, I think it would be easiest to trigger your transformations with a dummy action (e.g. `count()`, `collect()`) as the RDD will be materialized. During RDD computation, you can check the Spark UI to gather any performance statistics about the steps/stages/jobs used to create it.

This would look something like:

```
val text_file = sc.textFile(filename)

val words = text_file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
words.count()

val wordCount = words.map(word => (word, 1))
wordCount.count()

val wordCounts = wordCount.reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCounts.count()
```

Some notes:

- Since RDD's for all intents and purposes are immutable, they should be stored in `val`'s
- You can shorten your `reduceByKey()` syntax with underscore notation
- Your approach with `foreachPartition()` could work since it is an action but it would require a change in your functions since your are operating over an iterator on your partition
- Caching only makes since if you either create multiple RDD's from a parent RDD (branching out) or run iterated computation over the same RDD (perhaps in a loop)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the details. What do you mean by "foreachPartition() would require a change in my functions"? Should I change my code or does foreachPartition() change my RDDs in some other way than count()? If I should change the code, how should I do it exactly?

Comment: And what is actually the difference between foreach() and foreachPartition()? Or in other words: what is the difference between an element and a partition of a RDD?

Comment: What I mean is that `foreachPartition()` is an action that applies a function over partitions of an RDD (returned as an iterator) versus the elements of the RDD themselves. This is precisely the difference between `foreach()` and `foreachPartition()` as well. RDD's are made up of many distributed elements over a set of partitions. Abstractly, partitions divide elements into blocks of data, allowing us to view them as a metaphorical delimiter over the set of elements. Technically, partitions are much more than that and I would encourage you to do some more reading on these concepts.

Comment: So, if I use `foreach()` the change in my functions wouldn't be required, since `foreach()` applies a function on elements, not on partitions, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also simple invoke RDD.persist() or RDD.cache() after every transformation. but ensure that you have right level of StorageLevel defined.